# Test about prime gaps: which conclusions can be drawn from the results?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, hypothesis-testing, prime-gaps

I did the following test:

> For every prime, take the prime gap distance $dp$ to the previous prime and the next prime $dn$, then calculate $a=(pp\ mod\ dp)$ and $b=(np\ mod\ dn)$. If $a$ or $b$ $\in \Bbb P$ or equal to $1$ then the result is successful, if not the result is an error.

I have tested it with Python in the interval $[1,10^8]$ and the results are very interesting, the error percentage is very low, close to 1%:

```
Total errors: 62157 of 5761453 total primes. 
Successful primes: 5758741 in the interval [1,100000000]
%Error vs Total primes: 1.0788424378364276%
Family mod 3 errors: 59445
Uncategorized errors: 2712
```

Let $E$ be the set of prime numbers that are the error results of the test. I would like to isolate them at least partially, so I am trying to find a non basic commonality between them.

For instance, this is the error set $E$ for the interval $[1,57829]$, $1409$ is the first prime that does not succeed:

> $E=\{1409,2039,3109,10799,13669,16519,20369,27631,31859,42359,42989,44221,46549,47609,54959,55259, 55579, 55589, 57829\}$

When the interval is extended, other primes like $68863$ or $71647$ will appear, so not all of them will finish with $9$ or $1$.

I have tried checking at OEIS, and some basic modularity reviews, but without luck, I can not see any special relationship between them, apart from being primes, and that they belong to $1+6k$ or $5+6k$ (as usual because they are prime numbers) and that most of them finish with $9$ (this could be something important, but I can not see the reason behind). Maybe it does not exists at all, but maybe there is something I can not see.

Regarding to the value of the congruences, I have been able to verify that, at least in the tested interval, is in most of the cases a multiple of $3$ (I called them "family mod 3" errors), but I guess that as the interval gets bigger other multiples ("uncategorized errors") of a prime number will appear more often.

> The reason for this test is just that I wanted to learn if the prime gaps are following some kind of pattern, at least for some cases. The idea came from a very different test I did some days ago ([link here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283244/conjecture-about-the-product-of-the-primitive-roots-modulo-a-prime-number-pro)) for a quite different topic.

From those results, I thought that if there is such symmetry, maybe I could try to find similar patterns in between primes, so I started making the same test I wrote in the present question.

Originally I was using the minimum distance $d$ that applied to the prime $p$ makes $p-d$ and $p+d$ primes. Just by chance I realized that in most of the cases $(p\mod\ d)$ was also prime or $1$, so I tried to make a longer test. Finally, after some tests, I did the version of the test that I wrote in this question.

If somebody is interested to try or modify the test, here is the Python code:

```
def distance_primality():
    from sympy import nextprime, prevprime
    from gmpy2 import is_prime

    n=5
    errorcount = 0
    family_mod_3_errorcount = 0
    totalpr = 0

    print("RESULT"+"\t"+"P"+"\t"+"PP"+"\t"+"D1"+"\t"+"Mod"+"\t"+"pr/1?"+"\t"+"NP"+"\t"+"D2"+"\t"+"Mod"+"\t"+"pr/1?")
    print("-----"+"\t"+"-"+"\t"+"--"+"\t"+"--"+"\t"+"---"+"\t"+"-----"+"\t"+"--"+"\t"+"--"+"\t"+"---"+"\t"+"-----")

    test_limit = 100000000
    while n < test_limit:
        totalpr = totalpr + 1

        pp = prevprime(n)
        while not is_prime(pp):
            pp = prevprime(pp-1)
        np = nextprime(n+1)
        while not is_prime(np):
            np = nextprime(np+1)

        d1 = n-pp
        d2 = np-n

        if ((pp%d1==1) or is_prime(pp%d1) and ((np%d2==1) or is_prime(np%d2))):
            print("Success"+"\t"+str(n)+"\t"+str(pp)+"\t"+str(d1)+"\t"+str(pp%d1)+"\t"+"Yes"+"\t"+str(np)+"\t"+str(d2)+"\t"+str(np%d2)+"\t"+"Yes")
        elif (pp%d1==1) or is_prime(pp%d1):
            print("Success"+"\t"+str(n)+"\t"+str(pp)+"\t"+str(d1)+"\t"+str(pp%d1)+"\t"+"Yes"+"\t"+str(np)+"\t"+str(d2)+"\t"+str(np%d2)+"\t"+"No")
        elif (np%d2==1) or is_prime(np%d2):
            print("Success"+"\t"+str(n)+"\t"+str(pp)+"\t"+str(d1)+"\t"+str(pp%d1)+"\t"+"No"+"\t"+str(np)+"\t"+str(d2)+"\t"+str(np%d2)+"\t"+"Yes")
        else:
            if (pp%d1)%3==0 or (np%d2)%3==0:
                print("ErrF3"+"\t"+str(n)+"\t"+str(pp)+"\t"+str(d1)+"\t"+str(pp%d1)+"\t"+"No"+"\t"+str(np)+"\t"+str(d2)+"\t"+str(np%d2)+"\t"+"No")
                family_mod_3_errorcount = family_mod_3_errorcount + 1
            else:
                print("Error"+"\t"+str(n)+"\t"+str(pp)+"\t"+str(d1)+"\t"+str(pp%d1)+"\t"+"No"+"\t"+str(np)+"\t"+str(d2)+"\t"+str(np%d2)+"\t"+"No")
                errorcount = errorcount + 1

        n=nextprime(n)
        while not is_prime(n):
            n=nextprime(n)

    print()
    print("Total errors: " + str(errorcount+family_mod_3_errorcount) + " of " + str(totalpr) + " total primes" + ". Successful primes: " + str(totalpr-errorcount) + " in the interval [1," + str(test_limit ) + "]")   
    print("%Error vs Total primes: "+str(((errorcount+family_mod_3_errorcount)/totalpr)*100)+"%")
    print("Family mod 3 errors: " + str(family_mod_3_errorcount))
    print("Uncategorized errors: " + str(errorcount))

distance_primality()
```

I would like to share the following questions:

> 1. The error percentage seems very low, I have tested through $10^8$, but could it be just a result of the [Strong Law of Small Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers)?
> 2. Is there a way to isolate at least a subset of the primes at $E$?
> 3. Given these results, is there any hint about other type of test that I could do to know more about the observed behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you think these numbers are related?

Comment: The set of differences of your numbers has greatest common divisor $2$.  So they do not belong to any single congruence class except $1+2k$, which is of course obvious anyway.

Comment: "error results of a test" is not informative.  Please describe better how you got this list of numbers. Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Ross Millikan I know sorry, initially I wanted to know if there was something I did not see because the explanation of the test takes a little bit more of time. I will write it!

Comment: @RossMillikan added test explanation... thank you!

Comment: @vadim123 added the test I hope it will be better now, thank you!

Comment: @David thank you for the comment, I have added the explanation of the test, it might help to isolate them... initially I can not see any reason behind, but I wonder why are they mostly $p \equiv 9 \pmod{10}$. At least if I was able to isolate those finishing in $9$ would be cool.

Comment: The really good news is that we now know where the list comes from. It would be easy to extend it to much larger numbers, then you could enter it in OEIS.  The bad news is I (and I think others) don't know why we should care.  Extending the list to some number of at least $10$ digits seems easy.

Comment: @RossMillikan got the point, my fault since the beginning I did not focus properly the question.But please let me be positive about it. Knowing how the calculation is made, independently of the extension of the set, finding a commonality about a subset of those numbers might be possible, and I am struggling (if there is one). Imho, if there is a commonality, the length of the set would not be the main point. The percentage of numbers in the error set is very small compared to the total prime numbers in the successful set for any interval independently of the length (tested up to $10^7$).

Comment: It may also help to know why you are doing this. What is the significance of this test?

Comment: @ A.P. I added the explanation to the question, it was too long for a comment.

Comment: As a side-note, you may wish to use [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) instead of pure Python for your explorations: it is Python-based and provides a nice interface to many open-source mathematical libraries (while adding a bit of its own, too).

Comment: A.P. thank you for the suggestion, now I am migrating to Pari\Gp when I want to test big intervals, but for quick tests in small intervals still I am more familiar with the syntax of Python so writing the code is faster. I started to use Pari\Gp this very week :) (other MSE user suggested me to do so) and it works like a charm. I will have a look to Sage too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial low density of the "errors" and the fact that initially most of them end in $9$ can readily be explained. I don't know what you mean by "isolate" in question $2$, and I don't think there's any need for further tests as referred to in question $3$.

Except for the prime $2$ and the subsequent prime gap of $1$, primes are odd and prime gaps are even. Thus primes modulo prime gaps are odd. Of the odd numbers up to $13$, only $9$ is not either $1$ or a prime. Thus, until you get up to numbers that have prime gaps of at least $16$ on either side, the only way to get an "error" is to have a remainder of $9$ on both sides, and even that requires a prime gap of at least $10$ on either side, and even then there's at most a $1$ in $25$ chance for both remainders to be $9$. The typical prime gap of $\log x$ is $10$ at $\mathrm e^{10}\approx22026$. We can estimate the probability of two successive prime gaps of length $10$ at your first "error" value of $1409$ by considering the prime gaps as very roughly Poisson-distributed with parameter $\log x$; then the probability for a gap of size at least $10$ is

$$
\sum_{k=10}^\infty\frac{\log^kx\mathrm e^{-\log x}}{k!}=\sum_{k=10}^\infty\frac{\log^kx}{k!\cdot x}\;,
$$

which for $x=1409$ is about $0.2$, so the overall probability is about $0.2^4=.0016$ (two factors of $0.2$ on either side, one for the probability of a prime gap at least $10$, the other for a remainder of $9$ modulo $10$). So the low initial density of your numbers requires no further systematic explanation.

This also explains the frequent $9$s in the last decimal digit: The most likely prime gap to produce initial "errors" is $10$; the only (in)admissible remainder in that case is $9$; and this constellation only has to occur on either side in order to force the prime in the middle to end in $9$; that is, for the prime in the middle not to end in $9$, we need to have prime gaps of at least $12$ on both sides, which takes even higher primes to become likely.

From [an appropriate song](http://www.yellowpigs.net/yellowpigs/songs/algebraicnumbertheory):

```
I've looked at primes from both sides now
From norms and forms and still somehow
It's prime confusions I recall
I really don't know primes at all.
```

Comment: again to the rescue! thank you for the time you took for this. Then, as the interval of the test grows up, the easier it gets to get a value which is not prime gradually, I suppose due to the lenght of the longer gaps. And thanks for the song, I knew some limeriks too as well!! :) in those days still people had imagination and sense of humor, they are important to learn from the errors.